# Use image field in an entity query condition

Tags: 8, entities

How to use image field in a condition of an entity query?

To get X nodes which have no image as value of field_image I've tried this:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type','X')
->condition('field_image',NULL , '=')
->execute();
```

it doesn't work I got always empty result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:
$query->notExists('field_image');